# C#WPF checkboxes

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

I'm stuck with a problem regarding checkboxes from a WPF application to a SQL database.

I've arrived at a point where I can update the value of a specific item into the database but I can only update the value or from 0 to 1 or from 1 to 0, I'm searching for an IF Statement kind of thing, and I think I'm near the solution but the code isn't working and gives me the error" there's an error near ="
PLEASE

```
private void Row_DoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

        sqliteCon.Open();

        if (sqliteCon.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            {

            var currentRowIndex = dataGrid1.Items.IndexOf(dataGrid1.CurrentItem);

            //FROM 0 TO 1
            // string q = "UPDATE tabList Set selection = '" + 1 + "' WHERE idL="+ (currentRowIndex= currentRowIndex+1);


            //TEST4
            string q = @"UPDATE tabList
                         SET selection = (CASE 
                                            WHEN tabList.selection.Value = ' 0 '
                                            THEN tabList.selection.Value = ' 1'
                                            ELSE tabList.selection.Value = '  0  '
                                        END)
                     WHERE idL = " + (currentRowIndex = currentRowIndex + 1);





            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q, sqliteCon);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Dato Modificato");

            }
        sqliteCon.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Your sql is wrong, also you cannot access object variables inside double quotes....tabList.selection.value would be taken as a string not the value of checkbox

Answer (score 0):

Please replace this.

```
 string q = @"UPDATE tabList
               SET selection = (CASE  WHEN " + tabList.selection.Value.ToString() + " = 0 " 
                                       + " THEN 1 ELSE   0  END) WHERE idL = " + (currentRowIndex + 1);
```

Comment: Sintassi non corretta in prossimità di '='.'

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Sintassi non corretta in prossimità di '='.' it is a war versus c#

Comment: please get update solution. I hope it's working fine

Comment: i'm updating visual studio,wait for me please

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'not possible to call methods on bit.'

Comment: What is datatype of selection field ?

Comment: bit because i need a boolean datatype and in sql is bit,true or false,0 or 1

Comment: please get new solution

Comment: please get new solution

Comment: it doesn't find selection

Comment: Which value  get from "tabList.selection.Value" ?

Comment: Gravità Codice Descrizione Progetto File Riga Stato eliminazione
Errore CS0103 the name 'selection' doesn't exist in this context

Comment: selection in not find in your table (tablist)

Comment: selection is in tabList

Comment: SO?NOTHING ELSE?

Answer (score 0):

you might be  missing the single quote symbol. Try replace it with this.

```
 //TEST4
        string q = @"UPDATE tabList
                     SET selection = (CASE 
                                        WHEN tabList.selection.Value = ' 0 '
                                        THEN tabList.selection.Value = ' 1'
                                        ELSE tabList.selection.Value = '  0  '
                                    END)
                 WHERE idL = '" + (currentRowIndex = currentRowIndex + 1) + "'";
```

please let me know if this working. :)

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Sintassi non corretta in prossimità di '='.' same error:'(